# Optimization with matrix constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Is there a way to minimize $(A-BC)^2$ with respect to $B$ given that $BD=0$, where $A,C,D$ are known matrices such that operations above are possible?

Comment: Are $B,C,D$ square matrices ?

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: I am interested in analytic derivation of matrix B

Comment: You don't give precision on which matrix norm (or matrix entries functional)  you minimize...

Comment: I thought that matrices can be compared by multiplication from both sides by some vectors to obtain scalars

Comment: You mean minimize $X_0^T M Y_0$ for fixed $X_0$ and $Y_0$ ? It looks me very special.

Comment: Matrix $M$ is less than $K$ if for any $X,Y$, $X^TMY<X^TKY$. However I thought maybe it can be done easier. $(A-B)^2$ for example for any value of $A$ is minimized when $B=A$. Is it possible to solve problem in topic in such a way?

Comment: This kind of inequality works well for sym. positive definite matrices (Löwner order). I would be cautious to use it for more general matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lagrangian is:
$$L(B,\lambda) = (A-BC)^2 + \lambda BD$$
The KKT conditions are therefore:
$$2(A-BC)C^T +\lambda D=0$$
$$BD=0$$
A solution of this *linear* system is an optimal solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me any tips how to solve this system?

Comment: Depending on the sizes, use pen and paper or your favorite linear algebra software.